# Remove unknown characters from XML-file using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am developing a script that will read values from XML-files and parse it to an Excel table. The XML files is produced by a calculation software and contain unknown characters (�) as shown in the example below:

```
<be05key_fig version="10.19.7.22" date="21.11.2022 10.31" company="SBi" model="TEST_BE">
<table head="Be18 n�gletal: Munkes�huse bygning E"></table>
<table head="Transmissionstab, W/m�">
    <row><id>Transmissionstabsramme, almindelig</id><value>14,3</value></row>
    <row><id>Transmissionstabsramme, lavenergi</id><value>13,3</value></row>
    <row><id>Transmissionstab, beregnet</id><value>10,7</value></row>
</table>
<table head="Antal timer temperatur over">
    <row><id>26 �C (supplerende oplysning)</id><value>0</value></row>
    <row><id>27 �C</id><value>0</value></row>
    <row><id>28 �C</id><value>0</value></row>
    <row><id>29 �C (supplerende oplysning)</id><value>0</value></row>
</table>
</be05key_fig>
```

Is there a way in which I can remove the special characters directly from the Excel VBA so that what I parse looks something similar to:

```
<be05key_fig version="10.19.7.22" date="21.11.2022 10.31" company="SBi" model="TEST_BE">
<table head="Be18 ngletal: Munkeshuse bygning E"></table>
<table head="Transmissionstab, W/m">
    <row><id>Transmissionstabsramme, almindelig</id><value>14,3</value></row>
    <row><id>Transmissionstabsramme, lavenergi</id><value>13,3</value></row>
    <row><id>Transmissionstab, beregnet</id><value>10,7</value></row>
</table>
<table head="Antal timer temperatur over">
    <row><id>26 C (supplerende oplysning)</id><value>0</value></row>
    <row><id>27 C</id><value>0</value></row>
    <row><id>28 C</id><value>0</value></row>
    <row><id>29 C (supplerende oplysning)</id><value>0</value></row>
</table>
</be05key_fig>
```

I am accessing the XML script using the following:

```
Sub Test()
     
        Dim xmlObj As Object
        Set xmlObj = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        
        xmlObj.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        xmlObj.async = False
        xmlObj.validateOnParse = False
        xmlObj.Load ("C:\BE\Nøgletalsfil.xml")
        
        Debug.Print xmlObj.SelectNodes("//table[@head = 'Transmissionstab, W/m']/row/value")(0).Text
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: How are you accessing the xml file in Excel. Please show us that part of your code - then it is easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: Sure. I just added it to the question.

Comment: you could do a replace on the xml (`xmlObj.xml` will return it) and then reload it with `xmlObj.loadXML` - or you check the encoding itsself.

Comment: They are not unknown characters, they are characters that cannot be displayed by the text editor you are using to display the xml.  Try looking at the xml when loaded into something that can cope such as notepad++ or vscode.

Comment: Found a solution by opening the XML file in explorer and copying the unknown characters using a replace function in VBA. Thank you for your help.